# Nhibernate generating too many queries for one to one mapping

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-one

When the application loads, I am charging all the Campaigns into the memory:

```
var all = session.Query<Campaign>().ToList();
```

Campaign has one service.

```
public CampaignMap()
{
  Table("`TR_Campaigns`");
  Schema("dbo");
  Not.LazyLoad();
  Id(x => .Id).GeneratedBy.Increment().Column("CampaignID");
  References(x => x.Service).Column("ServiceID").Not.LazyLoad();
  // I also tried hasone and it is bringing the same result
}
```

This is the service map:

```
public ServiceMap()
{
  Not.LazyLoad();
  Table("`TR_Services`");
  Id(x => x.Id, "ServiceID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
  Map(x => x.Name,"ServiceName");
}
```

The problem is that when I have 100 campaigns, and each campaign has different service, the mapping generates 100 queries to get each the service for the each campaign. 
If for example, ServiceID 2 repeats itself in more than one campaign, the query `… WHERE  service0_.ServiceID = 2` will be only run once (which is good).

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT service0_.ServiceID   as ServiceID4_0_,
       service0_.ServiceName as ServiceN2_4_0_
FROM   [TR_Services] service0_
WHERE  service0_.ServiceID = 8
```

Is that normal? What will I do when I have 1000 campaigns with 1000 services or even more…

Thanks

**Update**:
I see your edit and I think that it is work.
but CampaignMap has more relations, for example:

```
 HasMany(x => x.LandingPageWeights).KeyColumn("CampaignID").Not.LazyLoad();
```

how do I handle it according to your query?
Doing `LandingPageWeights = x.LandingPageWeights` fails....
What is your suggestion about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it.
I have decreased to 2 queries:

```
var all = session.Query<Campaign>()
                            .Fetch(x => x.Service)
                            .Fetch(x => x.Supplier)
                            .ToList();
```

this one brings me the services in one query.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid n+1 issue by reading this article

http://ayende.com/blog/1328/combating-the-select-n-1-problem-in-nhibernate

and this so answer

[Prevent Fluent NHibernate select n+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581199/prevent-fluent-nhibernate-select-n1)

**Edit**

Select all data without n+1 issue

```
var items = session.Query<Campaign>().Select(x=> new Campaign
{
  Id = x.Id,
  Service = new Service
  {
     Id = x.Service.Id,
     Name = x.Service.Name
  }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I aware to this, but I have never saw it in action for one-to-one, this is why I have asked it.

Comment: @SexyMF I think its because you have not lazy column Service. You can use linq projection query or join to avoid it

Comment: IMHO, fetch-joins are not a good advise, there are several issues (eg. paging, multiple lists, distinct root problem etc). Ayendes blog is from 2006.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger Totally agree

Comment: @SexyMF then you should start from session.Query<LandingPageWeight>() and after selecting all, convert data to Campaign->LandingPageWeight on server side

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk, that is not possible, doing it from LandingPageWeight brings back single query per service item. So there is no way to do it directly from mapping? thanks

Comment: @SexyMF For example you can create table view with all data and map it