# NHibernate ToList() and then query over that causes multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a list of items ( that does not change ) so querying that with NHibernate and converting to in memory list like below

`List<Items> myItems = _repository.All().ToList();`

later when user does a search and clicks search button i do below

`myItems.Where(item => item.Name == searchTerm)`

I see that first code causes below query (equivalent not exact)

`SELECT * FROM Items`

then second code causes another hit to database, even though it is in memory object.

`SELECT * FROM Items Where Name = 'Stackoverflow'`

**What do i do to stop that unnecessary query ?**

Each item can belong to multiple users, so Item has a mapping like below

`HasMany(x => x.Users).KeyColumn("UserId");`

In a page that displays number of users that have Items i have code like below

```
foreach(Item item in AllItems)
{

   var itemName = item.Name;
   var itemUserCount = item.Users.Count;

}
```

Above is causing N queries on User table i.e If Items count = 100, 100 queries are executed on Users table to get the count.

```
How do i optimize the above mapping to work efficiently?
```

Resources:

http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/SelectNPlusOne

Comment: `SELECT N+1` problem. You should either eagerly load `Users` or, even better, only pull the data you really need in the first place.

Comment: @How do i eagerly load users. I am jst a beginner to NHibernate mappings. I did `Not.LazyLoad()` and it does not make a differene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off pulling only the data you need (using LINQ provider):

```
var result = session.Query<Item>().Where(x => x.Name == searchTerm).Select(x => new { x.Name, UserCount = x.Users.Count() });
```

(If you need to use that data outside of the function that was pulling it, you will have to select to a dedicated class, or at least a `Tuple`)

If you really want to pull all the data (using `QueryOver` API):

```
var result = session.QueryOver<Item>().Fetch(x => x.User).Eager.List();
```

That will probably create a `LEFT JOIN`, but you'd need to eagerly fetch all other entities you might need.

There's an easy way to see if you have a N+1 problem: dispose the session just after pulling the data. If you access a non-eagerly fetched related entity anywhere, you'll get an exception, which makes debugging such situations *that* much easier:

```
IList<Item> list;
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    list = session.QueryOver<Item>().Fetch(x => x.User).Eager.List();
}
var otherStuff = list.Select(x => x.OtherItem.Price).ToList(); // Boom, exception! OtherItem was not eagerly fetched.
```

Comment: Questions1 - Items returned from repository is `IEnumerable<Item>` which is converted to `List<Item>`. Then why should another query be issued, when all records are there in memory. I believed until now, that when `IQuerable,IEnumerable` when converted to list does not have any association with data source

Comment: @Deeptechtons When you are returning entities, then (usually) you're returning proxies which *still can call the session* while you're in session scope.

Answer (score 1):

What I see as an issue, is the User collection population, done for each item separately. The efficient way how to solve N+1 issue, is to use *batch* loading. Pretty clear explanation could be found in documentation [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

The [Prevent Fluent NHibernate select n+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581199/prevent-fluent-nhibernate-select-n1) question/answer is a bit old, so the syntax used there should be in your case:

```
HasMany(x => x.Users)
    .KeyColumn("UserId")
    .BatchSize(20) // here we go
    ;
```

This will reduce the amount of queries significantly. Because lot of users would be loaded at once.